# combine dictionaries and pass as output to another function

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I am learning python and coding. I am trying one web scraping example. I download the currency exchange data from a website and I want to compute average exchange rate for each currency over a 50 days period. The problem is that I am unable to do the following.

I get results from first function which should be in form of a dictionary and then pass these dictionaries to another function as argument and to perform averaging of those values. I am unable to pass correctly dict values to another function.
my code is as follow

```
import os 
import webbrowser
import requests as rq
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def saveData(path, date):
    session = rq.session()
    url = 'https://www.bnm.md/en/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date=' + date
    datastore = session.get(url)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
         f.write(datastore.content)
    data = ET.fromstring(datastore.content)
    '''
    elements = {}
    for element in data.iter():
        if element.tag in ('Name', 'Value'):
            elements[element.tag] = element.text
            print 'elements:', elements
    # Here I want to combine those all dictionaries in variable so that i can pass it as argument to another function
    return elements
    '''
# i replace the above triple quote code with the following below code
    elements = {}
    for tag, text in data.items():
        if tag in ('Name', 'Value'):
            elements.setdefault(tag, [])
            elements[tag].append(text)
    return elements    

def computeAverage(elements):  # I want to pass function saveData() results who are in dictioanry form to this function but I am unable to solve this issue.
    print elements

def main():
    dates = ['20.04.2016', '21.04.2016', '22.04.2016']
    paths = []
    for date in dates:
        path = '/home/robbin/Desktop/webscrape/{}.xml'.format(date)
        paths.append(path)
    data3 = {}
    for path, date in zip(paths, dates):
        data2 = saveData(path, date)
        print 'data2: ', data2
        for k, v in data2.items():
            data3.setdefault(k, [])
            data3[k].append(v)
         print 'data3: ', data3
    computeAverage(data3)



if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Also I am getting the results from saveData() function as dictionaries like this and it repeat every dictionary for the next item too which is wrong.

```
elements:  {'Name': 'Euro'}
elements:  {'Name': 'Euro', 'Value': '22.4023'}
elements:  {'Name': 'US Dollar', 'Value': '22.4023'}
elements:  {'Name': 'US Dollar', 'Value': '19.7707'}
elements:  {'Name': 'Russian Ruble', 'Value': '19.7707'}
elements:  {'Name': 'Russian Ruble', 'Value': '0.3014'}
elements:  {'Name': 'Romanian Leu', 'Value': '0.3014'}
elements:  {'Name': 'Romanian Leu', 'Value': '4.9988'}
```

Also what I tried to get results like this but failed

```
elements: {'Name': 'Euro', 'Value': '22.4023'}
elements: {'Name': 'US Dollar', 'Value': '19.7707'}
elements: {'Name': 'Russian Ruble', 'Value': '0.3014'}
elements: {'Name': 'Romanian Leu', 'Value': '4.9988'}
```

Updates:-------------

```
    elements = []
    for element in data.iter():
        if element.tag in ('Name', 'Value'):
            elements.append(element.text)
            # print 'elements: ', elements
    return elements
```

and in the main function() i make

```
for path, date in zip(paths, dates):
        data = saveData(path, date)
        # print 'data from main: ', data
        computeAverage(data)
```

and the output of "print 'data from main: ', data" looks like this

```
['Euro', '22.4023', 'US Dollar', '19.7707', 'Russian Ruble', '0.3014', 'Romanian Leu', '4.9988',.........'Special Drawing Rights', '27.8688']
['Euro', '22.4408', 'US Dollar', '19.7421', 'Russian Ruble', '0.3007', 'Romanian Leu', '5.0012',.....'Special Drawing Rights', '27.8606']
```

I am newbie to coding and if someone help me regarding these two problems. I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I agree with @Prakhar Verma.
Second, you didn't mention clearly what you want. But I can assume that you want to merge the data that you got from the 'saveData' function and then calculate average. So, here is the missing code.

```
data3 = {}
for path, date in zip(paths, dates):
    data2 = saveData(path, date)
    for k, v in data2.items():
        # you can move this line after declaring the data3 dict if keys returned by saveData are fixed i.e. name, value
        data3.setdefault(k, [])
        data3[k].append(v)

computeAverage(data3)
```

Update to saveData function:

```
elements = {}
for tag, text in data.items():
    if tag in ('Name', 'Value'):
        elements.setdefault(tag, [])
        elements[tag].append(text)
```

===================================================

Update 2:

```
def saveData(path, date):
    #session = rq.session()
    url = 'https://www.bnm.md/en/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date=' + date
    datastore = rq.get(url)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(datastore.content)
    data = ET.fromstring(datastore.content)

    # i replace the above triple quote code with the following below code
    elements = {}
    for element in data.iter():
        tag = element.tag
        text = element.text
        if tag in ('Name', 'Value'):
            elements.setdefault(tag, [])
            elements[tag].append(text)
    return elements

def main():
    dates = ['20.03.2016', '21.03.2016', '22.03.2016']
    paths = []
    for date in dates:
        #please edit this
        path = '{}.xml'.format(date)
        paths.append(path)
    data3 = {}
    for path, date in zip(paths, dates):
        data2 = saveData(path, date)
        for k, v in data2.items():
            data3.setdefault(k, [])
            data3[k].append(v)
    computeAverage(data3)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I am trying to get the all the currencies names and values from xml data which I extract successfully,  and then I want to pass this data to my function computeAverage() in order to perform some average calculations. I will try your code and will come back soon.

Comment: @magupt it returns only 'data3:  {'Name': ['Special Drawing Rights', 'Special Drawing Rights', 'Special Drawing Rights'], 'Value': ['27.8688', '27.8606', '27.8278']}
'    and these are the last values. what I need to extract all the values and pass them to the computeAverage function . my code is reproducible . I try to use another approach and will modify my question. Can you give it a look then whether it is correct or not. ..........because my goal is to get all data from saveData function and put as an argument to computeAvergae function. .

Comment: I update my questionby using list instead of dictionary because with dictionaries I am always getting only last values and I am unable to get all data.

Comment: i am saving data in data2  and merging in data3 , but I am getting wrong data. it  stores only last dictionary in the data2 always. I am trying to store and get all dictionaries in data2 , not only the last dictionary.

Comment: Ok, I got your problem. Your are over-writing the previous value in the dict to new "elements[element.tag] = element.text"

Comment: thanks a lot , i will give it a try and will come back soon.

Comment: I modify the code in my question as per your instructions, but in the results i am getting       'data2:  {}
data3:  {}
data2:  {}
data3:  {}
data2:  {}
data3:  {}
' . .Can you give my code a look. I am very thankful to you for your help.

Comment: you commented the return statement by mistake in saveData.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, but still same empty lists I am getting.

Comment: Sorry I edited the code too much. I converted the data.iter to dict locally leading to empty dicts.

Comment: thank you so much for your help and time. I will try your code now. .

Comment: thanks a lot. it works fine now. .I will accept your answer. thanks a lot for the help. .

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. :) Always happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

The 'saveData' function is returning data but you are not saving it in any variable. So what you need to do is save the data when it's returned from 'saveData' function and then send it as a parameter to 'computeAverage' function.

Please go through the basics of coding and follow any programming tutorial. :)